Photo Slideshow on 2nd Monitor, Disconnected From User GUI Login
I would like to display a slideshow on a 2nd monitor. I want it to act like a digital photo frame, cycling through pics with no interruptions 24/7:

upon reboot, slideshow starts automatically
when users log in our out of the Ubuntu GUI, it doesn't affect the slideshow
when main monitor is inactive, it turns off, without affecting the 2nd monitor

Is this possible? If I can do this with Ubuntu, I won't need to buy a Raspberry Pi to run the slideshow :)

when users log in our out of the Ubuntu GUI, it doesn't affect the slideshow -- I don't think this will be possible. I don't understand how you would do it with a Raspberry Pi either

@ArchismanPanigrahi, thank you for weighing in. On the Raspberry Pi, I would dedicate it to the slideshow, so that requirement would not be there. As it is right now, with my Ubuntu server, I am running Plex on it, and other things, and people log in and browse, etc. Ie, the requirement to use 2 monitors in the manner specified above does not apply if I buy a Raspberry Pi. :)

If you were continuously logged in as a single user, running the slideshow in the second monitor would have been easy. But with reboot and multiple users, I really don't know how to to it. One can run a program as a cron job. But I don't know how to particularly project it to the other monitor. If you have another monitor lying around, then buying a Raspberry Pi Zero for $5 would really be easier.

Just realized that the price of Raspberry Pi zero increased to $10
